# Wrap text at a specific width and full width background

Tags: html, css

I am working with WordPress Ultimatum Theme and am trying to style the content of my internal page layout's page titles.

The title is placed in the page as an `H1` with the text content directly inside, and the rest of the page content directly follows in a div:

```
<article>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="entry-content" >
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="wrapper" >
                <p>Some Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

I want to restrict my page to a maximum width, and I can do so to all of my page content, but I can't with the `H1` since it is just text content within the element.

Essentially, using similar HTML as above, I want my page to look like:

[image: Page Header With Desired Style]

...yet it looks like:

[image: Page Header Not Styled]

...instead.

Is there any way that I can force the text in my `H1` to wrap at a specific width (and center that block of text within the `H1`) without editing the HTML (that is, without any child elements in the `H1`? Maybe this could be done by targeting pseudo elements? I would rather not make a bunch of padding rules within media queries.

[**Here is a JSFiddle!**](https://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/mt1z94sp/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define left and right paddings :

```
h1 {
    width:100%;
    padding: 40px calc(50% - 300px);
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#337ab7;
}
```

the value of left and right paddings are `calc(50% - 300px)`. It makes text width always **600px**  when 600px less than 100%, or 100% when screen width is less than 600px.

https://jsfiddle.net/8u0rtb81/

Comment: I would rather not make padding rules, as I said at the bottom of my post. Using the padding rules that you suggested would make the width of the text 80% of the page width, instead of being a fixed width as I am asking for.

Comment: you mean that text of H1 should have min-width = 600px?

Comment: I've changed my answer. look at fiddle

Comment: This does work, and I am surprised at the [wide support for the calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). I'll let some more answers role in. I'm a little worried to use `calc()` just yet, due to the lack of support in opera, but I might just make a fallback rule to percentage-based padding if there isn't support for `calc()`. Good job. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can take off the `width: 100%` from the header and set `padding-left` and `padding-right` to some values, e.g.

```
padding-left: 15%;
padding-right: 15%;
```

Comment: I want the `H1` to stay full width. If I did what you are suggesting, the "blue bar" that is the header would no longer be the full width of the page.

Comment: `h1` is by default the width of the containing element -- I tested it and if you keep width as `100%` it overflows.